# Have the rules for suspension become draconian?

Tags: support, account-suspension

Answering a question from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597913/riya), I went to check over their earlier history (as I am wont to do occasionally) to discover that they'd been suspended for 7 days.

Now, given this account was created today and only one question had been asked, I'm wondering whether there's some sort of problem with the suspension process. The blog entries (and Jeff's comments) all seemed to indicate it would only be for repeat behaviour.

Now, I'm not trying to second-guess the powers that be, it may be that this is a sock puppet account (or some other problem not visible to the general population) but I'd hate to think we drive away new members with a potential bug.

If there is information that states this user *should* have been suspended, that's fine. No need even to explain why, just tell me to naff off and mind my own business :-)

But, if it's a genuine problem with the system rather than the user, I think we'd want it fixed.

Comment: I think that a page "what questions *of this user* have been deleted" is not visible even to the 10k+ users (or is there a search term for those?); I _suspect_ there may be other questions which have been deleted since. I don't know if that's the case here, but I've seen it happen to unwelcome users (e.g. spam/pure noise) before.

Comment: Possibly but, since the account was only created today (not much chance for a _lot_ of questions), there's probably some cross-account shenanigans going on that only the diamond-people can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspended the user because they asked a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859398/longest-increasing-subsequence) poorly phrased homework question.

It takes so much effort to bring these kind of questions up to standards, even the original was a tiny effort question.

Comment: Okay, no probs, that's probably a little more ... "strict in the application of the rules" than I would have been but you're the boss :-) In any case, it answered my question and so there's no bug we need to worry about.

Comment: I think a hard line need to be taken on poor homework question, otherwise we will have every student asking the some duplicate homework question!

Comment: I think what we _really_ is a homework.stackexchange.com so we can push all the h/w across to there. That way, we don't get the dross and lecturers will have an easier effort in detecting cheats :-)

Comment: Be glad it's only 7 days, he'll be of the hook in no time and back to asking poor questions again :P

Comment: @Ivo, the thing that frustrates me is that the community see these poor questions and do not downvote them, by downvoting them you can kick in the heuristic that stops the madness from continuing

Comment: @paxdiablo I agree I was pretty harsh in this case ... for the last few months I have mostly exposed my self to the "less" great content on SO. This has left me a bit jaded. I do feel this was the right decision in this case.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Super User moderating @waffles ;-) If it get's deleted you get your rep back right? I think it might be worth stating that fact a bit more clearly, because then some users might actually try it. They don't want to lose rep, just because they want to keep the site clean

Comment: @Ivo I almost managed to convince @Jeff to "recover" rep immediately upon post deletion ... I think he *may* agree to that change if pushed

Comment: **Push @JeffAtwood Push** Currently users will simply flag us mods and have us clean it up, I guess SU isn't at SO's scale of traffic that we couldn't keep doing that

Comment: This is one of the most horrifying things I've ever seen on SE. *You suspended a new user because their first question was a duplicate and poorly phrased?* Couldn't you have given them a chance to learn from their mistakes? Doesn't everybody ask some bad questions at the very beginning? [shocked]